# Raster calculation in R

Tags: r

I have two files from these website:
https://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/data/set/gpw-v4-population-count-rev11/data-download

And a shapefile of China from these website
https://gadm.org/download_country_v3.html

I would like to compute the difference between the raster population layers, that I can show a map where each pixel represents the change in the population in China.

I used this code

```
library(raster)
library(sf) 
library(tmap)

p_15 <- terra::rast("gpw-v4-population-count-rev11_2015_2pt5_min_tif/gpw_v4_population_count_rev11_2015_2pt5_min.tif")
p_20 <- terra::rast("gpw-v4-population-count-rev11_2020_2pt5_min_tif/gpw_v4_population_count_rev11_2020_2pt5_min.tif")
CHN <- sf::read_sf("gadm36_CHN_shp/gadm36_CHN_1.shp")
CHN <- sf::st_transform(CHN, crs="epsg:4490")|> terra::vect()
p_15<- terra::project(p_15,'EPSG:4490')
p_20 <- terra::project(p_20,'EPSG:4490')
p_15_crop <- terra::crop(p_15, CHN)
p_20_crop <- terra::crop(p_20, CHN)
p_15_mask <- mask(p_15_crop, CHN)
p_20_mask <- mask(p_2_crop, CHN)
```

The code above everything works fine.

Now I used overlay from the raster package to calculate the difference between the population layers to show the change in each pixel.

I gave these code

```
diff1520 <- overlay(p_15_mask, p_20_mask, fun=function(x,y){return(y-x)})
```

But I got the error message method not applicable??? What is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using objects from the "terra" package. There is no `overlay` method for these objects. The equivalent would be `app` or `lapp`, but in this case you can simply subtract.

You can get the data you are using with the geodata package (here using a lower spatial resolution).

```
library(terra)
library(geodata)
pop2015 <- geodata::population(2015, 10, path=".")
pop2020 <- geodata::population(2020, 10, path=".")
china <- geodata::gadm("China", level=0, path=".")
```

And then you can do, for example,

```
p15 <- crop(pop2015, china, mask=TRUE)
p20 <- crop(pop2020, china, mask=TRUE)
change <- p20 - p15
```

Or you can do:

```
d <- diff(c(p15, p20))
```

It is not clear why you use project. It is not a good idea, generally to project raster data before doing computations. You also did that [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/444434/doing-crop-extents-do-not-overlap/444436#444436) for no apparent reason. In this case it does not really do much anyway because `"EPSG:4490"` is equivalent to `"+proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80"`. But if you wanted to transform the data *after* the analysis, perhaps for display, you could do

```
pchange <- project(change, "EPSG:4490")  
pchina  <- project(china, "EPSG:4490")  
plot(pchange)
lines(pchina)
```

And with your file for China, you could do

```
CHN <- vect("gadm36_CHN_shp/gadm36_CHN_1.shp") |> project("epsg:4490")
```

Comment: I thought that overlay is from raster package?

Comment: The objects you are using are SpatRasters. `raster::overlay` does not know about these.

Comment: Okay many thanks for the clarification